# Excel file to database

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, arraylist

My excel file has some blank fields, How to leave this field blank also in database while inserting into database . 
When I was running this code successfully it inserting the data but if any blank record found in excel then it's facing a problem. 
Can anyone have any suggestion on this. I am almost done, only I need your help guys.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelToDb {
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        String fileName="D:\\demo.xlsx";
        Vector dataHolder=read(fileName);
        saveToDatabase(dataHolder);
    }
    public static Vector read(String fileName)    {
        Vector cellVectorHolder = new Vector();
        try{
            FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            //POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);
            XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(myInput);
            XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();
            while(rowIter.hasNext()){
                XSSFRow myRow = (XSSFRow) rowIter.next();
                Iterator cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
                //Vector cellStoreVector=new Vector();
                List list = new ArrayList();
                while(cellIter.hasNext()){
                    XSSFCell myCell = (XSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                    list.add(myCell);
                }
                cellVectorHolder.addElement(list);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); }
        return cellVectorHolder;
    }
    private static void saveToDatabase(Vector dataHolder) {
        String ID="";
        String FNAME="";
        String LNAME="";

        String Bytes="";
        System.out.println("List:"+dataHolder);

        for(Iterator iterator = dataHolder.iterator();iterator.hasNext();) {
            List list = (List) iterator.next();
           System.out.println("Here List: "+list.size());
           if(list.size()==2)
           {
            System.out.println("Dont do anything");
            list.add("NA");
            System.out.println(list);
           }
           else
           {
            ID = list.get(0).toString();
            FNAME = list.get(1).toString();
            LNAME = list.get(2).toString();
           }

            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/canteenmanagement", "root", "");
                System.out.println("connection made...");
                PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mst_input(ID,NAME,LNAME) VALUES(?,?,?)");
                stmt.setString(1, ID);
                stmt.setString(2, FNAME);
                stmt.setString(3, LNAME);

              //  stmt.executeUpdate();

                System.out.println("Data is inserted");
                stmt.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



        }
    }
```

Comment: What problem are you facing? Please share stack trace.

Comment: What means `blank record found in excel then it's facing a Problem`? Any exception?

Comment: Before adding to list, check your data is not empty.. That should solve ur problem

Comment: Do you mean you get a NullPointerException()? Then use `String.valueOf(list.get(0))` instead of `list.get(0).toString()`. But honestly, this code is horrible. You should at least move the connection handling outside your loop. Also, why do you store the `XSSFCell` objects in a list? This doesn't seem to make any sense. And then I doubt that `XSSFCell.toString()` will give the result that you expect.